# "As if a 29-year-old blond babe would be even vaguely interested…"

Tags: conditional-constructions

*The taxi driver thought Becky was a bit of all right. "Got any room for me in your rucksack, love,?" he said, winking back at us and showing an expanse of nicotine-stained teeth. **As if a 29-year-old blond babe would be even vaguely interested in some fat slob who'd never see fifty again and who had the remains of his breakfast on his beard**.*

Source: Cathy Kelly: Thelma Louise and the Lurve Gods, in Irish Girls About Town, p. 55.

I would have two questions regarding the part in bold in the above sentence:

1. Why  "As if a 29-year-old blond babe would be…" is used instead of  "As if a 29-year-old blond babe were…" which should be according grammar books the correct choice.
2. I am not sure what "never see fifty again" means in the context.

Comment: you have been around ELL for a while: you should know that it's best to leave it a little while before accepting an answer.... even if it's mine :-)

Comment: -1 not including a link to the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider these two sentences:

> I need money *- fact*
>   As if I needed money *- hypothesis*

For most verbs, we describe a hypothetical situation using a **backshift** - moving back one tense. It is the same trick we do for reported speech: here is [an article](http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-reported-speech.php) about it.

**be** is an exception: there is a special form called a subjunctive, which we only use for hypothetical situations. Sometimes we are a bit slack and just backshift.

> I am rich *fact- present*
>   As if I were rich *hypothesis - subjunctive*
>   As if I was rich *hypothesis - backshift*

A few other verbs are exceptions. Quoting from that article about backshifting:

> The modal verbs *could, should, would, might, needn't, ought to, used to* do not normally change.

So, now we get to your sentence:

> A 29-year-old blond babe would be interested in... *- fact*
>   As if a 29-year-old blond babe would be interested in... *- hypothesis*

As you can see, **would** did not change when we switched to a hypothetical sentence.

**never see fifty again** is an expression meaning that somebody is over fifty. Here are [lots of examples](https://www.google.com.eg/#q=%22never+see+fifty+again%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr) of its use.

Comment: Thanks for your exhaustive answer. I did not take into consideration that there is backshifting in play. "The taxi driver thought…"

Comment: @bart-leby: You are welcome. There is backshifting there too, because *we use reported speech when we are saying what other people say, think or believe*: "Becky **is** a bit of alright" -> "The taxi driver thought Becky **was** a bit of alright.". But the backshifting in the second sentence is completely separate, and it is because **as if** starts off a hypothetical sentence, which is like a wish, and we use backshifting for wishes too.

Comment: But why in my grammar book are these sentences: 1. you looked as if you were enjoying it. 2. he is speaking as if he were drunk. No use of "would".

Comment: @bart-leby , 1) you are enjoying it -> as if you were enjoying it. As I said in my answer, be (am/are/is) -> were (subjunctive). 2) you would enjoy it -> as if you would  enjoy it. As I said in my answer, would does not change.

Comment: OK. Finally I have understood the difference. Thanks for your patience with me.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the difference between these two scenarios:

Suppose a blonde babe *were interested* in an old guy with food in his beard. How would she act?

Suppose an old guy with food in his beard attempted to chat up a young babe. Do you suppose she *would  be* interested?